# How can I refactor this code to be more concise?

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using Python to extract some data from the Google Analytics Core Reporting API. I've managed to use functions to make different calls to the API (below are just two examples) but I'm wondering how can I refactor this to make it even shorter? There's quite a lot of duplicate code still.

```
def get_pvs(service, profile_id, start_date, end_date, type, data):
    if type == "url":
        return service.data().ga().get(
            ids = 'ga:' + profile_id,
            start_date = start_date,
            end_date = end_date, 
            metrics = 'ga:pageviews', 
            dimensions = 'ga:pagePath',   
            filters = 'ga:pageviews!=0',
            sort = '-ga:pageviews',
            max_results = '10000').execute()
    elif type == "author":
        return service.data().ga().get(
            ids = 'ga:' + profile_id,
            start_date = start_date,
            end_date = end_date, 
            metrics = 'ga:pageviews', 
            # Post Author
            dimensions = 'ga:dimension2',
            sort = '-ga:pageviews',
            max_results = '100').execute()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a dictionary with type-specific arguments, then apply that with `**kw`:

```
def get_pvs(service, profile_id, start_date, end_date, type, data):
    if type == 'url':
        kwargs = {
            'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
            'filters': 'ga:pageviews!=0',
            'maxresults': 100
        }
    elif type == 'author':
        kwargs = {
            'dimensions': 'ga:dimension2',
            'max_results': '100'
        }
    return service.data().ga().get(
        ids = 'ga:' + profile_id,
        start_date = start_date,
        end_date = end_date, 
        metrics = 'ga:pageviews', 
        sort = '-ga:pageviews',
        **kwargs).execute()
```

I left the common arguments in place. if `type` can have more values, then you probably need to add a `else: return None` too.

Comment: we should still put this piece inside the function right?

Comment: Yes, I've added the function definition line to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
TYPE_SETTINGS = {
        'url': {
            'dimensions': 'ga:pagePath',
            'filters': 'ga:pageviews!=0',
            'max_results': '10000',
            },
        'author': {
            'dimensions': 'ga:dimension2',
            'max_results': '100',
            },
        }

def get_pvs(service, profile_id, start_date, end_date, type, data):
    if type in TYPE_SETTINGS:
        return service.data().ga().get(
                ids = 'ga:' + profile_id,
                start_date = start_date,
                end_date = end_date,
                metrics = 'ga:pageviews',
                sort = '-ga:pageviews',
                **TYPE_SETTINGS[type]).execute()
```

The `TYPE_SETTINGS` can be easy to modify in case that you need to define more `type` rather than `url` and `author` in the future .